Standalone Ubuntu ported to Hyper-V has no ethernet
This configuration is a little different from what most people do. I have an Ubuntu 20.04LTS installation on an SSD which runs fine if I boot my desktop computer into it directly. But I'd rather run it in a VM, since I use Windows 10 for most things. I set it up in Hyper-V, and it's working except for the ethernet. Here's what I did:

I created an external virtual switch, and associated it with my NIC. I turned off all three extensions. The only checkbox that's on is "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter".
I created a VM, gave it 16G of RAM (out of 32G), 8 processors (out of 20), and told it to use the external virtual switch. I didn't give it a virtual disk.
Once it was created, I opened its properties, created a Hard Drive, and selected the appropriate physical disk.
I set it to boot from the hard drive, turned off Secure Boot, and disabled checkpoints.

The VM boots up fine, except for networking. I've also tried creating a private virtual switch, and using the default internal one. Those don't work either.
ifconfig -a shows eth0 and lo, and both say UP and RUNNING. eth0 shows a few TX packets, none dropped, no RX packets, and no errors, but "ping" says "Network is unreachable". It has an IPv6 address, but no IPv4 address. systemctl status networking shows a failure due to timeout:



I had to edit /etc/network/interface to comment out the enp6s0 name used when I boot directly, and add an eth0 section. It contains auto eth0 and iface eth0 inet dhcp.
It smells like the missing IPv4 might be the culprit. But when I examine the vEthernet connection in Windows, it shows IPv4 and IPv6 with addresses and internet connectivity. Any ideas how to diagnose this further?

More info: My Arris router shows the VM's MAC address, but says the Allocation is "pending", meaning that it doesn't know whether the device is DHCP or static. Yet the networking.service status shows that dhclient spat out a bunch of DHCPDISCOVERs. Perhaps these packets aren't getting through the Hyper-V manager and out to the router?

That's about converting my physical disk to a virtual disk. I want to keep the physical disk, in case I need to boot directly into it.
